# get row count of excel sheet from javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

i am trying to get total number of rows in my excel sheet with javascript .
here is my code

```
      var Excel;
      Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      Excel.Visible = false;
      a= Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).value;
      alert(a);
```

this show the value at 1st index , but i was wondering if there is any option of getting the total rows of this active sheet .

Thanks

Comment: Excel.Workbooks.ActiveSheet.Cells returns a Range object. Did you try using Count? Something like this? 'Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Count'

Comment: thanks , it show "1"  because 1,1 means 1st row, 1st column , so definitely there's only 1 first row and 1 first column in an excel sheet , but i want to know total number of rows..  if i use .ActiveSheet.Cells.Count   it give me total rows in a sheet which are 677777 , but i want to get only the rows which are active/filled for that i tried .ActiveSheet.Cells.active.Count  but its not giving any thing , not working

Comment: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` - something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
a = Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).value;
```

with

```
a = Excel.Rows.Count;   //Depending on excel version, you will get either 65536 or 1048576
```

or

```
a = Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells.UsedRange.Count;    //It will provide total used rows.
```

---

Note: ActiveXObject is available only on IE browser. So every other useragent will throw an error